# Defining Routes in .NET 3.5 with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, routes

I am trying to downgrade a .NET 4.0 app to 3.5 and I am having a hell of a time trying to define a route:

In 4.0, it looks like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("UploaderService", 
          new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(UploaderService)));
```

It looks like .NET 3.5 does not have the ServiceRoute object.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: The route stuff was added in 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no support for WCF routes in 3.5 - this feature was introduced in 4.0. In 3.5 you have to live with the "ugly" .svc URIs for REST services.

So for the route example you mentioned, you'd add a file called something like UploaderService.svc with the following content:

```
<%@ ServiceHost
    Language="C#"
    Debug="true"
    Service="UploaderService" 
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Remember to use the fully-qualified name of UploaderService, if it's not on the "" namespace. And the file is usually a single-line file, I only broke it down here for readability purposes.

Comment: Can you point me to an example by any chance?  I've never actually had to deal with .svc services.

Comment: Edited the answer with an example.

Comment: How would I then call a method from a client?  http://site.com/UploaderService/MyMethod.svc?

Comment: site.com/UploaderService.svc/MyMethod

Comment: or if you're posting a file to upload, it'd be something like POST site.com/UploaderService.svc/Upload?fileName=file.txt (and the file would be on the request body). That assumes this decoration for the operation: [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Upload?fileName={fileName}")] void Upload(string fileName, Stream fileContents)